# Regex to match certain word but not a particular combination

Tags: regex

I have 15 titles as follows:

```
fruits-and-flowers-themeA
fruits-and-flowers-themeB
fruits-and-flowers-just-test-themeA
themeAfruitsandflowers
nice-fruits-and-flowers-themeA
botanical-names-themeA
```

I want a regex to help me get only those titles with "themeA" in them, but it should not include "nice" and not include "just-test" or "just-tests".

I tried

```
^(?!.*just-test|*just-tests|nice).*?(?:themeA).*,
```

but I still get fruits-and-flowers-just-test-themeA in the output.

How to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What language are you using? There are more options depending on language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can use a single regex with lookaheads (see [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ3vY3)):

```
^(?!.*nice?)(?!.*just-tests?).*themeA.*
```

1. The `^` asserts that the match starts at the beginning of the string (so we don't match a subset of the string
2. The `(?!.*nice?)` is a negative lookahead that asserts that at this position in the string, we cannot find any characters followed by `nice`
3. The `(?!.*just-tests?)` is a negative lookahead that asserts that at this position in the string, we cannot find any characters followed by `just-test` and an optional `s`

As a further tweak, you can compress the lookaheads into one using an `|` alternation as in anubhava's answer.

**Option 2 without lookaheads (Perl, PHP/PCRE)**

```
^(?:.*(?:nice|just-tests?).*)(*SKIP)(?!)|.*themeA.*
```

This one doesn't use lookaheads but just skips the unwanted titles. See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/uD7kM7).

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex with `negative lookahead`:

```
^(?!.*?(?:just-tests?|nice)).*?themeA.*$
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hO7rU4)

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the answer. Both your answer and Zx81's answer works. I had to chose one!

Answer (score 0):

Use two different regular expressions for clarity and simplicity.

Match your string against one regex that matches themeA:

```
/themeA/
```

and then check that the string does NOT match the one you don't want:

```
/nice|just-tests?/
```

Doing it in two different regexes makes it far easier to understand and maintain.